# How to abstract generic code shared among many controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application, I have an user model/controller. An user can have multiple videos, images and blog items. User, and the items can have comments. So I've got the following controllers

- user
- user/comments
- user/picture
- user/picture/comments
- user/video
- user/video/comments
- user/blog
- user/blog/comments

The problem is, all the comments controllers are almost identical, and the code is becoming hard to manage. Now I'd like to specify a central place, e.g. a app-level CommentsController, which would have the methods to be called from sub-controllers.

What is the best way to do that?

How would for example the following code look after such a change:

```
class User::Picture::CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def delete_all
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @picture = @user.pictures.find(params[:picture_id])

    if @picture.has_access(current_user)
      @picture.comments.destroy_all

      redirect_to :back, :notice=>t(:actionsuccesful)
    else
      redirect_to :back, :alert=>t(:accessdenied)
    end
  end
end
```

The @user && @picture initializations are same among different methods (destroy, delete_all, create, index). Could they be moved into a before_filter which would be a sub-controller specific? And then, delete_all would be implemented in the CommentsController?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the code is that generic, two options:

1) a module including shared methods

Example:

```
module CommentsActions
  # actions, methods
end

class User::Picture::CommentsController <ApplicationController
  include CommentsActions
  #your additional actions
end
```

2) subclassing comment controllers from one controller

Example:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  # actions, methods, filters etc...
end

class User::Picture::CommentsController < CommentsController
  #your additional actions
end
```

Comment: Used the second way. Works great! I created Shared::CommentsController which has index, create, destroy, delete_all methods. Also a few private methods that can be defined again in the underlying controllers, such as set_object that sets @object to be used (called from before_filter). Total code: from 370 lines to 217 lines :)